# Subdomains do not work without the leading www

Tags: subdomain

What is the difference between the following URLs?

- http://www.forums.example.com and
- http://forums.example.com ?

Actually I've created a new subdomain in my website and it's working fine when I try to access without www (i.e http://forums.example.com) But when I try to give URL like http://www.forums.example.com it is showing "Page not found".

Why is this and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: what webserver are you using ?

Comment: IIS 6.0 (I hosted site in godaddy)

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, www. is also considerd a Subdomain, hence when you setup hosting on a provider (i.e Slicehost) they tell you to put www in the subdomain list (again if I am not mistaken). If you really want www.fourms.duckyetc you can set up a script to do some matching, i.e

```
if url contains www.fourms.ducketc then go to here else go somewhereelse
```

Comment: exactly so, www simply another subdomain. so www.forums is a subdomain of a subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a cname for `www.forums.duckyvideos.com` and also configure your webserver to respond to that cname. There is nothing automatic about www prefixes on the web. It's just a convention that websites are accessible with or without the www. Everyone hosting a website has to explicitly set up a second cname for the www prefixed version of every site they put up.

Comment: "...to respond to that cname" ... or to that IP address! (which since it will likely be the same, would be to do nothing, web-server wise)

Comment: @mjv: In the case of a webserver that is set up for virtual hosting (ie. more than one web site hosted on a single IP address), you would most certainly need to configure the web server to respond to a new cname.